# Troubles with Matsubara sum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, thermal-field-theory

In appendix C of *Quantum Physics in One Dimension* of Thierry Giamarchi, it is claimed that (See (C.22)) after performing the Matsubara sum over the bosonic frequencies $\omega_n=2\pi n/\beta$ in
$$\frac{1}{\beta\Omega}\sum_k\sum_n e^{i(kx-\omega_n\tau)}\times \frac{-i2\pi\omega_n/k}{\omega_n^2+u^2k^2}, $$
and taking the $\beta\to\infty$ limit we are left with (see (C.25))
$$-i\int_0^\infty\frac{dk}{k}e^{-\alpha k}e^{-u\cdot\text{sign}(\tau)\tau}\sin(k\cdot\text{sign}(\tau)x),$$
where the factor $e^{-\alpha k}$ is introduced to ensure convergence. The "naive" result would be (see (C.26))
$$-i\text{sign}(\tau)\arctan\left[\frac{x}{u|\tau|+\alpha}\right]$$
I have had troubles when trying to reproduce these results. First I do not get (C.25) when computing the Matsubara sum. I have used the weighting function $g(z)=\theta(\tau)(-\beta f_B(-z))+\theta(-\tau)f_B(z)$, where $f_B(z)$ is the Bose-Einstein distribution (see [Matsubara sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency)). On the other hand, if I take the limit from the beginning and compute the sum as the integral
$$\sum_n \to \int d\omega \frac{\beta}{2\pi},$$
using complex integration then I still get something slightly different, namely,
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \text{sign}(\tau)\frac{e^{-\alpha k}}{k}(e^{ikx}e^{-uk|\tau|}-e^{-ikx}e^{uk|\tau|}).$$

Where I messed up?

Comment: Can you make the question self-contained, so that we do not need to look for a copy of the book to find out whether these are Bose on Fermi $\omega_n$'s.

Comment: @mikestone Yeah, I forgot to point that out, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will help, but I often use the following dedimensionalized algebra to do the Bose sums:

$$
 \frac 1{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+M^2}=
   \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty   \frac 1{2|M |} e^{-|M||\tau+2\pi n|}, \quad \hbox{(Poisson Summation)}\nonumber\\
   =  \frac 1 {2|M|} \frac{\cosh(\pi -\tau)M}{\sinh \pi |M|}, \quad 0<\tau<2\pi,\nonumber\\
   = \frac 1{2|M|} e^{-M\tau} +\frac 1 {|M|}\frac{ \cosh M\tau}{(e^{2\pi |M|}-1)}\quad 0<\tau<2\pi.\nonumber\\
   %= \frac 1{2M} (\coth \pi M\cosh M \tau- \sinh M\tau) \nonumber
 $$
The first line come from applying Poisson summation to the zero temperature expression
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ik\tau}} {k^2+M^2}=\frac 1 {2|M|}e^{-|\tau||M|} 
$$
and has the  physical interpretation as  the method-of-images sum over the  $n$-fold winding of the particle trajectory around the periodic imaginary time direction.
The passage from the first  to second  lines is just summing  the two  geometric series from  $n=0$ to $ \infty$ and $n=-\infty$ to $-1$.

You can get the extra factor of $\omega_n=n$ by differentiating wrt $\tau$

Comment: May you clarify how in the first line you performed Poisson summation but there is still a sum over $n$? Are you integrating over $k$ first even though it does not appear at the initial expression?

Comment: I am not touching $k$. The $n$ on the left and the $n$ or the right are independent dummy summation labels. I could have called then RHS $n$ anything, but I am lazy. so I reused $n$. Poisson says that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \tilde F(n)$ where $\tilde F$ is the Fourier transform of $F(n)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.